# What query should I write to calculate the cumulative salary of employees from the salary table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

A salary table is given and we need to write a single query which prints the cumulative salary of employees.
For Example:

```
Emp  Sal
A    10
B    15
C    20
D    5


OutPut:

Emp  Sal   Cum_Sal
A    10      10
B    15      25
C    20      45
D    5       50
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in some RDBMS (like PostgreSQL or SQL Server 2012 or Oracle) it's possible to use window function:

```
select
    Emp, Sal, sum(Sal) over(order by Emp) as Cum_Sal
from employees
```

if it's not possible, you can use self-join

```
select
    e1.Emp, e1.Sal, sum(e2.Sal) as Cum_Sal
from employees e1
    inner join employees e2 on e2.Emp <= e1.Emp
group by e1.Emp, e1.Sal
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f18ff/10)</kbd>**

Note that in both cases you have to define order for rolling sum (in queries above, it's ordered by `Emp` column).

Comment: Just a minute I am running this query.
Thanks for replying.
thank you so much :)

Comment: If there is no column for Cum_Sal then would it create one after the query executed or the original table need to have an empty column as Cum_sal?

Comment: Cum_Sal is calculated column in query, original table doesn't have to have empty column

Comment: select *from Emp;
id    sal
A     10
B     15 
C     5
D     20

select e1.id,e1.sal,sum(e2.sal) as Cum_Sal from Emp as e1 inner join Emp as e2 on e2.Emp<=e1.Emp group by e1.Emp,e1.sal;
It is showing an error:
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: there is a problem in the above query. you there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38170/discussion-between-niss-and-roman-pekar)

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL please try this:

```
select NAME,SAL,sum(SAL) 
over(order by SAL rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as cum_sal 
from employee
```

Answer (score -2):

[image]

```
select e.name,e.joining,sum(e_1.increment) from employee e inner join employee e_1 on e.name=e_1.name where e.joining>=e_1.joining group by e.name,e.joining
```

table is like below 
you can use same approach